# Using DELETE LIMIT inside TRIGGER

Tags: mysql

How to use `DELETE INTO .... ORDER BY ... LIMTI` inside the trigger? Here this is what I try

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.qty > 0 THEN
        SET @QTY = 0;
        REPEAT
            INSERT stock_fifo(id, sku_id, slot_id, stock_at)
            VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.sku_id, NEW.slot_id, NEW.stock_at);
            SET @QTY = @QTY + 1;
        UNTIL @QTY > NEW.qty END REPEAT;
    ELSEIF NEW.qty < 0 THEN
        DELETE FROM stock_fifo
        WHERE slot_id = NEW.slot_id AND sku_id = NEW.sku_id
        ORDER BY id
        LIMIT -NEW.qty;
    END IF;
END
```

It said there is error around

`LIMIT -NEW.qty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIMIT` expressions have to be "nonnegative integer constants" (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)) so `LIMIT -NEW.qty` is a syntax error. You can loop the `DELETE` the same way as you loop the `INSERT`:

```
SET @QTY = 0;
REPEAT
    DELETE FROM stock_fifo
    WHERE slot_id = NEW.slot_id AND sku_id = NEW.sku_id
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1;
    SET @QTY = @QTY - 1;
UNTIL @QTY < NEW.qty END REPEAT;
```

Comment: The second option does not work as we cannot use dynamic statement in the trigger. I guess first option is the only way to go.

Comment: @invisal Sorry - I always forget that MySQL limitation. I'll remove that part of the answer.